# The "Project and interest" section in PDF has not got info about "Linux and Unix" site

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I have got "Unix & Linux", StackOverflow and CodeReview accounts on my career page: https://stackoverflow.com/cv/skwllsp. However when I prepare a PDF file https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/11369/export/pdf-preview in the "Project and interest" section I see only info about my "Stackoverflow" account:

```
Projects & Interests Stack Overflow – https://stackoverflow.com/users/184968 October 2009 - Current
Written 353 answers. Active in c++, c, linux, gdb, profiling and 14 other tags.
```

How to add info about the "Unix & Linux" account to the PDF file generated by the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to add this info. However it is a little bit strange.

So I added my "Unix & Linux" account directly in "Projects & Interests" section and added a description. So now it looks like:

```
Projects & Interests 

Stack Overflow – http://stackoverflow.com/users/184968 October 2009 - Current
Written 353 answers. Active in c++, c, linux, gdb, profiling and 14 other tags.

Unix & Linux – http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/17530/skwllsp
Q&A for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems
Written 36 answers. Active in bash, process, linux, tcp tags.
```

Well, to me it is a little strange that even though I added the "Unix and Linux" account to my career page I still have to add my "Unix and Linux" account as a project in order to see it on my CV. However since there is no other way to add my "Unix and Linux" account to CV then this way is OK.